# REGEX - last number on the row

Tags: regex

I need to find last number in the string. For instance:

> Recept 400    303,45  2,00    272,03

I need to find the number 272,03. However, there can be sometimes a space after comma so the strings than can look like this

> Recept 400    303,45  2,00    272, 03

Any ideas how to this and cover both options by REGEX?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what regex parser you're using but if you were to be using a language like Ruby, you can do the following:

```
/\d{1,},(\s+)?\d{2}$/
```

which will catch:

Recept 400 303,45 2,00 **272,03**

Recept 400 303,45 2,00 **272, 03**

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex :

```
(\d+,\s*\d+)$
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/Ke1qA9/1

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot. Is not there something more general?

What if the number is 35,10 but read by OCR as 3 5,10?
Or what if it is connected to the previous number with something? E.g. 1,00.237,41